# How to get $-4(S+\cos\theta)$ when it depends on the area of the triangle in the unit circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> Assume $S$ square units $(u^2)$ is the area of the region whose color is blueberry. Consider that in this unit circle the diameter of the circle is $1$ [decameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decametre). Given what it is known in the figure from below, find $-4(S+\cos\theta)$.
>
> [image: Sketch of the problem]

The choices given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\cos 2\theta\\
2.&\sin 2\theta\\
3.&-\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
4.&-\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
\end{array}$

I'd like to note that there might be some typo in the given choices as the original source it is not very clear in this aspect. Thus I'm okay with an answer as **long it is well justified**. My main question here is not **exactly trying to get an answer matching the choices but rather a way to understand the meaning of the arrows indicating the direction of the angle in the unit circle** with that being mentioned. Please read my question from below.

For this problem I'm also stuck, and the reason for that is that the angle $\theta$ I'm not sure if it comes from the $\textrm{x-axis}$ or from the vertex on the right triagle which is contiguous to the small square looking from the bottom.

When an angle goes as this, in the clockwise direction I assume it is negative right?. But it doesn't help me much on how **should I properly put this information in the solution**.

I mean I always get confused when **that arrow goes in the clockwise direction**.

Because of this weird looking figure (at least to my understanding) there is not proper way to find that area. Does it exist something that can I do?. Because of the way how I'm stuck with this it would really help a lot a solution which would solve this sort of problem.

It seems that a drawing might be required to solve this problem thus can someone help me?. **Since the part which confuses me the most is the way how it is used the arrow in the clockwise direction I kindly appreciate and beg someone could explain this to me in the right way to avoid getting confused.**

Comment: Is the source of the problem trustworthy?

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ is irrelevant. The related acute angle is relevant as well as that $cos(\theta)=-cos(RAA)$.

The area S can be expressed in terms of RAA or $\theta$:

$S=R^2\cdot cos(RAA)=-R^2\cdot cos(\theta)$

The problem is that neither of the provided answers works.

$4(S+cos(\theta))=4cos(\theta)\cdot(1-R^2)=3cos(\theta)$

Comment: I think the problem here is **why** $\cos\theta=-\cos(RAA)=$ for which I belive you're using $\angle NOM$ (see Nima's drawing for this). The most important part of my answer has not yet been adress and is **why is it negative?**. Is it because when you go in that direction indicated by the arrow, does it mean it is resting on the third quadrant where the cosine is negative?. Please confirm.

Comment: The source is trustworthy. It may be some sort of typo in the answers so I believe your conclusion is correct. My question was aimed at **what should be the interpretation when an arrow for an angle goes in that direction**.

Comment: This is basic trigonometry. There is no interpretation for the arrow. When the angle terminates in the second quadrant, the cosine is the opposite of the cosine of its related acute angle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You have to think how you can connect $S$ to $\theta$. I am assuming $\theta$ is the point $N$ for which its $cos$ value is negative. Let's say the diameter is $d$. I cannot finish it since it seems it goes nowhere. You might get some idea:

$$ S = \frac{1}{2} MH \times PN = \frac{1}{2} (OM sin\alpha) \times PN = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{d}{2}sin\alpha) \times d = \frac{d^{2}}{4}sin\alpha $$

Note that:

$$ sin(\alpha) = - cos\theta $$

Thus:

$$ -4 (S + cos\theta) = -4 (\frac{d^{2}}{4}(- cos\theta) + cos\theta) = (d^{2}-4)cos\theta  $$

Even if you change the reference point of $\theta$ from $A$ to $A'$, it seems it doesn't help simplifying this equation. Is the source of problem trustworthy?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply buddy. Thanks for your nice diagram. Yes I understood what you meant now. It took me some time to figure this for myself. My problem is **how should you understand the direction of the arrow for the angle** could it be that from that **perspective** one should underatand that the angle $\theta$ in this case is resting on the third quadrant and hence cosine function will be negative?

Comment: My second problem with understanding your answer, is why it seems to be different in sign from the answer from above?. Could it be that you missed up some signs there?. Can you please explain this to me?. By the way the source is trustworthy. But *there is a chance that it might be some typo in the answers* so I believe your conclusion is correct so I'm okay with that, the thing is that my question in principle was aimed at **how to correctly understand the direction of the arrows when looking at the unit circle**

Comment: Therefore I request you could include some foreword or explanation of this in your answer. Can you do that please?. I will kindly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The clockwise arc starting at the positive $x$-axis and ending at the arrowhead is *slightly thicker* than the rest of the circle. So I will assume that $\theta$ is measured from the positive $x$-axis, and is rendered opposite from the usual counter-clockwise orientation. Let $\alpha$ be the angle $\angle NOM$ as in @NimaS's drawing. Traveling clockwise from the positive $x$-axis we will encounter $\frac\pi2$, then $\alpha$, then $-\theta$ to complete a full circle:
$$
\frac\pi2 + \alpha -\theta =2\pi
$$
and therefore $\sin\alpha=\sin(2\pi+\theta-\frac\pi2)=-\cos\theta$.

I agree with @NimaS that the area $S$ equals $\frac14\sin\alpha$ (since the diameter of the circle is $1$). Given all this, there is no chance that any of the choices will match $-4(S+\cos\theta)$, which seems to be a rather strange quantity to compute. Notice that if we drop the "$+$" then the quantity $-4(S\cos\theta)$ equals
$$
-4S\cos\theta=-\sin\alpha\cos\theta=\cos^2\theta
$$
which is almost one of the choices.